# WPF: Simplest of DataTriggers

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I'm just trying to learn DataTriggers. What's wrong with this simple code? It tells me that "Source" is not a property of FrameworkElement.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Sent">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Approve_64_Trans.bmp"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="SendFailed">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Cancel_64_Trans.bmp"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Also, is it correct to use a value "SendFailed" or "Sent" when the Status field is of enum type and SendFailed and Sent are two valid enum values?

Comment: Being relatively new in WPF, I can't really decide which of the Chris and Baboon's answers is technically superior. I really wish I could mark both of them as answers, but based on the facts that Baboon's answer doesn't require any extra namespaces and references (you need to add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity to use Chris's answer), I'll mark that as answer. Thanks both of you.

I also verified that you can use enum members directly in DataTrigger's Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that kind of trigger in a style, like so:

```
  <Image>
     <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Sent">
                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Approve_64_Trans.bmp"/>
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="SendFailed">
                 <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources\Cancel_64_Trans.bmp"/>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </Image.Style>
  </Image>
```